# A better way to minimize the code for the if else condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am kind of new to SQL. Please check the below code. I am trying to get some data from my table by using the @isActive bool property. If this bool is true then I am just adding one extra condition for getting the values. I kind of come up with the below code, Is there any other possible way to minimize this code?

```
declare @firstname nvarchar(100);
declare @surname nvarchar(100) ;
declare @isActive bit ;

create table #Table1
(
    Serial_number int,
    Unique_Id uniqueidentifier
)
insert into #Table1
if @isActive='false'
Begin
select
    t.Guid
from UserTable t -- this table contains my data
where 
t.FirstName = @firstname
t.SurName = @surname
End
else
Begin
select
    t.Guid
from UserTable t
where 
t.FirstName = @firstname
t.SurName = @surname
t.isActive = @isActive -- this is the only codition I am adding extra for this if else codtion. 
End                    -- Is there a better way to minimize this code?

select * from #Table1
drop table #Table1;
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Anish

Comment: Is this [tag:sql-server]? If so, please edit and add that tag. If not, please edit and add *the appropriate tag* for your product.

Comment: Erland Sommarskog wrote a good article on [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` instead, as below

```
insert into #Table1
select
    t.Guid
from UserTable t -- this table contains my data
where t.FirstName = @firstname
AND t.SurName = @surname
AND (@isActive = 'f' OR t.isActive = @isActive)

--Case Alternative
--AND ISNULL(t.isActive, 'a') = case when @isActive = 'f' then
--ISNULL(t.isActive, 'a') else @isActive end
```

Note: Change datatype of `@isActive` to either `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case in WHERE and ON clauses.

Comment: Yeah Appreciated, I have changed accordingly, Thank you very much.

Comment: It's my pleasure :)